# MySQL workbench giving an error "Unsupported operating system" when running under Windows 8.1

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm running Windows 8.1. I've successfully installed MySQL Workbench with server. The connection is successfully established but it says:

> "You are running Workbench on an unsupported operating system. While it may work for you just fine, it wasn't designed to run on your platform. Please keep in mind if you run into problem."

The main problem is that I can't execute queries so I'm unable to work with MySQL databases as expected. Here is a screenshot of what I am seeing.

[image: Screenshot off the error.]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means exactly what it says where the language states *"it wasn't designed to run on your platform"*, so unfortunately this appears to be an instance where the unsupported OS version is experiencing a bug and the entire message meaning is applicable.

### Workaround

As a workaround, try an older version of MySQL Workbench from [MySQL Workbench (Archived Versions)](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/) site. Just select an older version from the **Previous Version** drop down.

> **Trial and Error**
>
> This may have to be a trial and error type of solution so uninstall
>   the version of MySQL Workbench with the bug, reboot, install an older
>   version, and then test. If you run into the same bug with the previous
>   version, keep moving back and following that same process to
>   uninstall, reboot, install, test with each version.

[image]

> ### [MySQL Workbench (Archived Versions)](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/)
>
> **Please note that these are old versions. New releases will have recent bug fixes and features!**
>
> ```
> Product Version: <select the version>
> Operating System: <select the os>
> ```
>
> Select the <kbd>`Download`</kbd> button once the needed version and OS is selected

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8.1

Even if you've installed the latest version of MySQL you may proceed to control panel, uninstall latest workbench, download from archive MySQL workbench 6.3 CE and install it. It will solve your issue.

In XAMPP if someone is facing MySQL not connecting the best recommended solution is:

While installing MySQL when it asks for a port number change 3307 or 3308 instead of running around in `my.ini`